# This is code I have typed in python. Whenever I run it shows a syntax error in the "else" in line 15. What is wrong with it?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    # Your code here
    l = len(aStr)/2
    mid = aStr[len(aStr)/2]
    if mid == char:
        return true
    elif mid > char:
        return isIn(char,aStr[:l]
    else:
        return isIn(char,aStr[l:])
```

Comment: close the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ")" at the end of the line before the else.